# Dockerfile: code 127 when trying to RUN shell-script

Tags: shell, docker

Running **Docker Toolbox** on **Windows 10 host**.

There is a **Dockerfile**:

```
FROM 16.04
...
RUN if [ some_condition ]; then ./foo.sh; fi
...
```

There is a **foo.sh**:

```
#!/bin/bash
...
echo 'Me working'
```

Now when trying to build the Docker image:

```
docker build -t name_of_the_image .
```

Getting error:

```
Step 7/12 : RUN ./foo.sh
 ---> Running in e7e0703d3f8f
/bin/sh: 1: ./foo.sh: not found
The command '/bin/sh -c ./foo.sh' returned a non-zero code: 127
```

I would assume error **127** would be the Docker doesn't see the bash. Any suggestion how to fix this?

---

**Edit:** already copying all files into the Docker, **Dockerfile**:

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04
MAINTAINER Mr Anderson "mr@anderson.com"

# set workdir
COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app

# Run scripts
RUN ./foo.sh
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some further investigation:

- Using CMD over RUN is not a perfect solution because of the way those commands work. RUN can be used any amount of times, to build Docker image layer by layer, while CMD can be executed only once when the image has been build.

In my case the solution was to:

- Open `./foo.sh` file with VIM and run: `:set fileformat=unix` and save the file.

Long story short: the line ending in the shell-script were incorrect and had to be converted to the Unix ones.

Comment: Wow, this turned out to be a my issue too. Spent a lot of time searching for the answer and turned out to be line endings....
Welcome to the world of running docker in a Windows machine.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to copy/COPY the file into the container before you can execute/RUN the script.

Also since you're using a relative path when you call the script be sure to set a WORKDIR.

```
COPY ./foo.sh /app/foo.sh
WORKDIR /dir
RUN chmod +x /app/foo.sh
RUN if [ some_condition ]; then ./foo.sh; fi
```

Also make sure the script is executable.

Comment: Good thought. Unfortunately, this is not the case - already copying all files to the docker with `COPY . /app`.

Comment: lol nice, i deleted that comment, so glad you saw it before it was gone... but glad that did the trick.  have fun out there!

Answer (score 0):

I was building an Alpine Linux image which had a bash script called in the Dockerfile and hit this same error

### Troubleshooting: Simplification

I had a really busy Dockerfille with lots going on, so needed to simplify it to help isolate the root cause of the fault.

So I copied my docker file and stripped-out all but the bare minimum plus the part calling the script then renamed it `Dockerfile.COPY`.

I also simplified my build command which was also really busy.

Testing in this simpllified environment revealed the fault was the product of (2) errors and neither of them was related to the script or how it was being called in the Dockerfile:

### Error 1 Fix:

There was a missing package. In the Dockerfile I hadn't included `bash` with the other Alpine Linux packages.

```
RUN apk add --no-cache --update bash app1 app2
```

### Error 2 Fix:

My `docker buildx build` command had a syntax boo-boo. I had added many tags to the `build` command and my local context (the "dot") had become nested between tags. So when I reduced complexity of the command by removing all but a single tag, the context was no longer nested and voila! The 127 error was cleared.

After realizing what happened, I added the tags back BEFORE the context (so that it was now at the end of the command) and tested using my simplified `Dockerfile.COPYY` and the 127 error was cleared.

```
time docker buildx build --no-cache --platform linux/arm64 \
-t f1linux/testrepo:test1 -t f1linux/testrepo:test2 -t \ 
f1linux/testrepo:test3 -f Dockerfile.COPY . --progress=plain
```

### Conclusion:

The 127 error feedback lead me on a wild goose chase trying to find a fix for the way the script was called in the Dockerfile when that part was 100% correct and it was (2) other completely unrelated faults noted above.